# Perl script executed by Cron failed

Tags: linux, perl, cron

I maintained a database (MySQL), I would like back up some data to the database using a perl script. To save my trouble, I would like cron to do it for me, I inserted the following using crontab

```
*/5 * * * * blctrl /home/blctrl/code/perl/tt01.pl
```

However, cron never does its job, any suggestions to get it done? The Linux installed is Centos 5?

Comment: What is `blctrl`? What happens when you run that command yourself? Did you check your `mail`?

Comment: Does *tt01.pl* begin with `#!/usr/bin/perl` or similar? Are you sure the correct Perl interpreter is that one?

Comment: There might be something interesting in `/var/cron/log`

Answer (score 3):

```
*/5 * * * * blctrl /home/blctrl/code/perl/tt01.pl
```

That looks like the syntax for `/etc/crontab`, the system-wide crontab file.  The first 5 words indicate when to run the command, the 6th is the account under which to run it, and the rest of the line is the command to execute.

(The clue was that the command is under `/home/blctrl`, which would be the home directory for the account `blctrl`.)

The syntax for your own crontab, the one you feed to the `crontab` command, is different.  You don't specify an account name, because it only runs under your own account.

Try this:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/blctrl/code/perl/tt01.pl
```

**EDIT**: Incidentally, the first thing I would have tried when encountering a problem like this would be to replace the command with something simple, perhaps `touch /tmp/FOO`.  That would have told you whether the problem was with your Perl script or with your crontab.

Comment: Hi, blctrl is the username in the linux system

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer first, however, I removed the blctrl, it still does not work. The touch command works, maybe, I guess it is related with environment variables. How could I trace the problem, find out what make it fails?

Comment: It depends on what `/home/blctrl/code/perl/tt01.pl` does (and I have no idea about that).  What happens when you run it from the command line?  Are there any MySQL-specific variables in your environment?  Try adding some print statements to `tt01.pl` to narrow down where it fails.